# Cannot see the data in my mongo container but able to connect to my remote mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a nodejs app and i am able to connect the app to my remote mongo database using the following compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  ddmbackend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4100:4100"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

I am able to post apis directly to the remote server but my mongo container is acting only as a connection. I want to connect my container with the remote database in such a way that whatever database and collections that are available on the server should also be available in my container and should also reflect api changes.
any ideas it would be very helpful.
Thanks in advace

When was getting into the mongo container the container was empty

Comment: What's the role of the local MongoDB server in this setup?  Can you delete the `mongo` container and just connect directly to the remote database?